# php javascript detect page change

Tags: javascript, php, screen-scraping

I would like to detect specific changes in the HTML of the page. The HTML of the page is refreshed with Ajax. At a given time interval, lets say 1 second, an ajax call is made and some html is modified. I would like to way to detect such thing, and when a certain word is present send an email.(send a http requst to a url from which i send an email-this part i know how to do).

Is this possible?

I can not scrape the page with php because its not in a publicly accessible website. And i simply can not scrape the page. I get all kind of errors.

Comment: When you say the page is refreshed with ajax, do you mean new content is loaded into the page via ajax (ok) or ajax triggers a page refresh (technically incorrect).

Comment: I mean a div from the page is loaded with Ajax

Answer (score 0):

for my knowledge, and i have tried, you cant bind a change listener on the complete document or body tag i.e. with javascript. you can bind the change listener to every form element, but not on normal dom nodes i think. perhaps there is a way you can specify your own elements.

what you can do, rewrite your ajax listener and everytime ajax is sucess you have a change in your site.

php is not event driven, and php is definitly the wrong language for it.

Comment: this is a hard one to understand, but you can put javascript in the success part of a ajax request that will get run each time the ajax request is successful.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you have complete dev access to this website which is unclear, you could just put some php code in the php function that is called by the ajax request that checks the content being submitted to it or return back to the browser for your keyword and if present, send your email.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. When the JavaScript refreshes the data, it's just making an HTTP call to some resource. I would locate that call, and determine the response. It is likely JSON or XML, but could be HTML or something else. It may prove easier and more reliable than parsing an HTML page.

Comment: That is the problem. When i call the url i do not get the expected answer. I get an error.